# XQuery - How to use eq (=) on a group of values

Tags: xpath, xquery

I would like to know how you could query for one specific language, this is a related XML-snippet:

```
(...)
<Guide guideID = '5'  gname = 'Dexter Schneider'>
<Lang lname = "{'Spanish' , 'German' , 'English'}"/>
</Guide>
(...)
```

I tried with:

```
element Result {
//Guide[Lang/@lname = 'German']
}
```

but I only get the results where "German" is the only language in "lname". I suspect this is either because of a bad XML-document (no warnings from XQuisitor about the syntax), or because the "="-sign can only compare one exact string with another. Could anyone shed some light on this, and show me how a proper query would look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In your specific case**, you can use `//Guide[contains(Lang/@lname, 'German')]`.

**More generaly**, the value of your attribute is a string and not an array. 
For your use case, you can use sequences but you first have to build the sequence.

For example, if you have an XML like that :

```
(...)
<Guide guideID = '5'  gname = 'Dexter Schneider'>
<Lang lname = "Spanish German English"/>
</Guide>
(...)
```

You can use the following XPath 2.0 syntax (xquery compliant) :

```
//Guide['German' = tokenize(Lang/@lname,' ') ]
```

The `tokenize` function creates a sequence and the `=` tests what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your XQuery engine, this XPath should work:

```
element Result {
//Guide[contains(Lang/@lname, 'German')]
}
```